# Cannot run npm run wbp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, npm, webpack, asp.net-core

I tried to use this tutorial, to install webpack to asp.net core project

> https://codeburst.io/how-to-use-webpack-in-asp-net-core-projects-a-basic-react-template-sample-25a3681a5fc2

Here is command in my package.json

```json
{
 "name": "streamline",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "wbp": "webpack wwwroot/source/app.js wwwroot/dist/bundle.js"
 },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "devDependencies": {
  "webpack": "^4.16.0",
  "webpack-command": "^0.4.1"
 }
}
```

But when I run it with `npm run wbp` I get this

> > internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:596
> > throw err;
> > ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'import-local'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
> at Object. (/Users/nemesises/Documents/GitHub/streamline/Streamline/node_modules/webpack-command/lib/cli.js:11:21)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! streamline@1.0.0
> wbp: `webpack wwwroot/source/app.js wwwroot/dist/bundle.js` npm ERR!
> Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the streamline@1.0.0 wbp
> script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
> likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/nemesises/.npm/_logs/2018-07-13T14_21_24_555Z-debug.log

How I can fix it?

**UPDATE**

After I make this

```
"wbp": "webpack --entry wwwroot/source/app.js --output wwwroot/dist/bundle.js"
```

Reinstall npm packages and try to run command

I got this error

> > ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'wwwroot/source/app.js' in
> > '/Users/nemesises/Documents/GitHub/streamline/StreamLine' npm ERR!
> > code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2 npm ERR! streamline@1.0.0 wbp:
> > `webpack --entry wwwroot/source/app.js --output wwwroot/dist/bundle.js` npm ERR! Exit status 2 npm ERR!  npm ERR!
> > Failed at the streamline@1.0.0 wbp script. npm ERR! This is probably
> > not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
> > above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/nemesises/.npm/_logs/2018-07-14T19_45_54_642Z-debug.log

But I got this file in my folder!

If I use my old command and create `dist/bundle.js` it works, but `bundle.js` is empty

Answer (score 0):

`webpack --entry wwwroot/source/app.js --output wwwroot/dist/bundle.js`

--entry says what is the entry

--output what to output to

Answer (score 0):

It seems like npm has failed to install the dependencies properly. Try to reinstall the local packages by executing the following commands in your package.json directory:

`rm -rf node_modules
npm install`

If everything goes fine with `npm install` you should be able to run `npm run wbp` successfully.

Comment: The `app.js` module is most likely missing from the `wwwroot/source` directory relative to your `package.json`.

You can try to navigate manually to the given directory and check if the module is there. If the module is missing, you can either find it is currenly located and move it there, or update your `wbp` script entry argument to point to the actual file path.

Comment: but `app.js` is not missing

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently digging my way into this ASP.NET CORE + Webpack + Script combo. Luckily, I've found my solution, hope this can fit your case. Take a look at my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "blindforced",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "wbp": "webpack --mode production wwwroot/source/app.js --output wwwroot/dist/bundle.js",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development wwwroot/assets/app.js --output wwwroot/dist/bundle.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production wwwroot/assets/app.js --output wwwroot/dist/bundle.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me: `webpack --entry ./wwwroot/source/app.js --output wwwroot/dist/bundle.js`, note `./` in `./wwwroot`.